# Mongoid map reduce in output collection to simulate join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

I'am using mongodb/mongoid and i run two map/reduce process in two differents collections with the same key,values and return format.

*(like in this tutorial : http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/ )*

I use the "out" option to simulate a merge between the two outputs to simulate a join operation...

My "joined" collection is well filled but only when i iterate the result !

**if i do** :

> Model_A.collection.map_reduce(map_1, reduce).out(reduce: "my_collection)
>   Model_B.collection.map_reduce(map_2, reduce).out(reduce: "my_collection)

**It does not work**, the collection "my_collection" is empty !

**If i do** :

> res_A = Model_A.collection.map_reduce(map_1, reduce).out(reduce: "my_collection)
>
> res_A.each do| res |
>     puts res.inspect
>   end
>
> res_B = Model_B.collection.map_reduce(map_1, reduce).out(reduce: "my_collection)
>
> res_B.each do | res |
>     puts res.inspect
>   end

**It's working,** my collection "my_collection" is well filled with the "joined" values ...

For big datasets, iterating at web application server side in ruby is just ugly ...

Does anyone ever faced this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first map-reduce you can just call `#first` and your output collection will be filled with all values (actually for the 2nd map-reduce it is also true but you probably want to iterate over it's result in any case).

So, instead of

```
res_A.each do| res | puts res.inspect end
```

just do

```
res_A.first
```

You can easily check that collection is filled in mongo console:

```
db.my_collection.find()
```

FYI it is due to

```
Model_A.collection.map_reduce(map_1, reduce).out(reduce: "my_collection)
```

doesn't trigger `db.collection.mapReduce()` function in MongoDB in fact. Instead, it returns an instance of the `Mongoid::Contextual::MapReduce` class and you can think of it as something similar to `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Comment: I was suspecting that is was returning a "contextual" things, if i can trigger the request with a "first", it's perfect ... I was just affraid of retrieving all the results at application server side.

Thank you

Comment: welcome) fyi, it's common here to accept correct answers